# Xcode can't find GPUImageHistogramEqualizationFilter, but can find other filters

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, gpuimage, xcode7

I'm having a problem where Xcode is unable to find `GPUImageHistogramEqualizationFilter`, though it is able to find other filters without trouble.  I got `GPUImage` going by dragging `GPUImage.xcodeproj` and the `Resources` folder into my project, and adding `GPUImage.framework` to the `Embedded Binaries` of my target.  Here's a minimal example showing the error:

```
import UIKit
import GPUImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let filter1 = GPUImageBrightnessFilter() // No sweat
    let filter2 = GPUImageHistogramEqualizationFilter() // No dice

}
```

I get the following error when instantiating `filter2`:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'GPUImageHistogramEqualizationFilter`
```

I checked `GPUImage.xcodeproj` -> `GPUImage` -> `GPUImage.h`, and both `GPUImageHistogramEqualizationFilter.h` and its superclass `GPUImageFilterGroup.h` have been imported.  I also checked the `FilterShowcaseSwift` example app to see if I could find a hint there, but it seems to have been left out (at least, it's not part of the `enum` in `FilterOperations.swift`).

I'm using Xcode Version 7.0 beta (7A121l), and I got whichever version of `GPUImage` was on GitHub yesterday.

**Update:**

I found that `GPUImage.xcodeproj` -> Targets -> `GPUImageFramework` -> `Build Phases` didn't have `GPUImageHistogramEqualizationFilter.h` listed under Headers, and didn't have `GPUImageHistogramEqualizationFilter.m` listed under Compile Sources.  Unfortunately, after I added them, I get a new warning in addition to the old error:

```
Umbrella Header for module 'GPUImage' does not include header 'GPUImageHistogramEqualizationFilter.h'
```

This error persists after cleaning, closing Xcode, and deleting derived data.

Whenever I start playing with Build Phases, I always feel a bit like [this guy](http://vdrueaoy4hzmkcs4dg5ai1sx.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/No_idea_what_i_m_doing.jpg).

Comment: Good catch @Eric D., thanks for the edit.

Comment: I'd suggest to use cocoapods or carthage to manage your dependencies, it'll make your life way easier. https://cocoapods.org/?q=gpuimage and https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

Comment: @LoïsDiQual agreed--I've used Cocoapods previously and it can be an absolute lifesaver.  But, as I've had trouble getting it to play nice with git, I'd still like an answer to the question *sans* Cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project -> **Build settings** -> change **Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)** to **No**

The warning should go away.